# AJAX IE doesn't find element ( getElementByID() )

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've searched everywhere i could but i did not find a solution to this specific problem.

To put it simple. I have a page with some javascript code and a DIV. I use ajax to load a second page inside that DIV. The loaded page has one element which id is "someid".

someid is `<input type="hidden" id="someid" name="someid" value="sdasasdadad" />`

then, on the loaded page i call a function that is defined on the "global" page that begins with these two lines:

```
var=document.getElementById("someid").value;

alert(var);
```

works fine on firefox but not on IE. On IE it doesnt display the alert and doesnt execute any code after those lines.
I think the problem is that when the javascript code was evaluated, the "someid" element didnt exist yet and IE doesnt seem to understand that now it exists after i loaded a page using ajax. I hope i made myself clear?

I need to do things this way because this is only a small part of a bigger interface. I have no knowledge on jquery but it should work with this javascript code too i guess! How can i make this work?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It's likely that your code is looking for the element BEFORE your AJAX request has inserted the element into the DOM. without your JavaScript code it's difficult to determine.

Comment: Are you actually using `var` as the variable name?

Comment: can you change this var value=document.getElementById("someid").value;

alert(value);

Comment: also if the var thing was a typo please upload your code that handles the onsuccess part of ajax.. basically the entire js code associated with this action

Comment: Yes i dont use var as a variable name it was just for the example! sorry! xD the var is actually called time.

Comment: im sure IE is not looking for the element before it is inserted by AJAX. I know this because i call the function via onClick after the page is completely loaded

Comment: can  you update your code according to my last comment?

Comment: Does alert(document.getElementById("someid")) print undefined?

Answer (score 3):

`var` is used to declare variables. Do something like `var el = document.getEl...`

This is assuming your code is exactly the same as your production code, otherwise please show us the **real code**

EDIT: Since you said it "works" in Firefox, your code is probably inconsistent, since `var = 3`  in Chrome throws a `SyntaxError` and I imagine it would do so in Firefox too.

Comment: time=document.getElementById("time").value;
alert(time);

Answer (score 0):

The `var` word is a keyword in Javascript.  Here you are trying to use a keyword as an identifier which is illegal.  Using a name other than `var` like `myVar` will fix the problem.

```
var myVar =document.getElementById("someid").value;
alert(myVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that. **var** is a reserved keyword for javascript

```js
var someVar = document.getElementById("someid").value;

alert(someVar);
```

Comment: of course. i put var just for the explanation. Sorry! the real name of the variable is time.

Answer (score 0):

I would try debugging this by alerting the element and then the value :

```
var element = document.getElementById("someid");

alert(element);

var valueOfElement = element.value;

alert(valueOfElement);
```

I'm sure you haven't but you can't use var as a variable name, it's a Javascript keyword.

Comment: what is the use of an alert like '<object> Object'??

Comment: Sure, that was just to be absolutely sure there was a value other then NULL or false being retrieved. If his page has many AJAX actions kicking off, nodes may be removed, inserted etc... it's worth to make sure something is being retrieved when calling getElementById